# Twitter Bootstrap Form. How do I capture values entered in the form?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am a Twitter Bootstrap newbie and I had to dive in to the deep end a bit. I have a project where I have a form embedded in a modal. The form is used to pass values to a JS object. There is no server involvement at all.

The form:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms

The modal:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

I have a few questions:

1. How and where are values captured/stored in the form when I press "submit"?
2. How do I pass these values back to my JS object.

Note:
I have been getting up to speed on custom data attributes. Do they play a role here?

UPDATE
Here is the form code I am using:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFilterMinimum" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Minimun</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFilterMinimum_TRACK_LABEL" placeholder="Minimum">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFilterMaximum" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Maximum</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFilterMaximum_TRACK_LABEL" placeholder="Maximum">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

So the idea is I want to convey the minimum and maximun values to a JS object I have implemented when I press the "Apply" button.

Comment: A form and a modal don't do anything. Post your JavaScript so we can see what's going on. A complete code example is always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the variables on close of the modal and use them in anyway you want. This is using jQuery UI's `dialog` function:

```
$( "#MyDialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function() {
                        $('#name').val($('#firstname').val() + " " + $('#lastname').val());
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    //do what you want with the values here
                    $('#firstname').val("");
                    $('#lastname').val("");
                }
            });

            $( "#name" ).click(function() { $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog( "open" ); });
        });
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/THWPU/)

Comment: Thanks ssergei. For context, I am an iOS dev getting up to speed on JS and Bootstrap. I am using Bootstrap for a form embedded in a modal. My project cannot use any JQuery beyond what is in core Bootstrap. Part of my confusion is the Bootstrap form and modal appear to be black boxes to me at this point. I just want to convey the values entered in my form to a JS object.

Comment: Bootstrap has its own modal. You can use `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` function on submit and then listen for the `hide.bs.modal` event to grab the values from the form.

Comment: Yep. I'm still fuzzy on the details of your answer but it sounds like the way to go. Thanks a lot. Cheers.